# What is the difference between jbehave core and web distributions?

Tags: java, bdd, jbehave

The page on http://jbehave.org/download.html allows me to download the core and web distributions of JBehave. Can anyone tell me what are the differences between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From JBehave Doc](http://jbehave.org/reference/web/stable/)

> What is JBehave Web?
>
> JBehave Web is an extension of JBehave Core, providing support for
>   web-related access or functionality.
>
> Web Runner
>
> The Web Runner provides a non-technical front-end that does not
>   require access to a build system nor to source control. It allows the
>   user to run stories - both synchronously and asynchronously - via a
>   simple web interface. It also allows the user to find matching steps
>   methods and to explore steps patterns by auto-completion.
>
> Selenium Integration
>
> The Selenium integration module allows the user to drive the
>   verification of web application behaviour using Selenium.
>
> The Web Runner allows the running of any type of story, not just those
>   related to web behaviour.